# How to untag in Bitbucket

Tags: tags, mercurial, bitbucket, release

While the UI of Bitbucket allows to tag a given commit of a mercurial repository, I can't find a way (web-based or command-line) to remove the tag, which could be added by mistake (actually, there is no confirmation prompt to add it). When used to control releases, this kind of mistake might be a major problem.

Comment: @cantSleepNow this is a mercurial question, not git.

Comment: @marco.m Yes, I saw that second after I voted to close, but I have then retracted the vote. Thx for pointing it out. When I click to close now it says `You voted to close this question 6 hours ago 
You retracted your vote 6 hours ago` weird... Maybe it was just the automatic comment that was left over...

Comment: @cantSleepNow ah I see, no probs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mercurial has a built-in help mechanism for all commands. In this case, `hg help tag`
shows:

```
options:

 -f --force        force tag
```

Let's add a tag and then move it:

```
$ hg init foo
$ cd foo/
$ touch a
$ hg add a
$ hg commit -m 'add a'
$ hg tag 0.1.0
```

What is the history?

```
$ hg log -G
@  changeset:   1:9352d8865ee5
|  tag:         tip
|  summary:     Added tag 0.1.0 for changeset a4cab63b7c86
|
o  changeset:   0:a4cab63b7c86
   tag:         0.1.0
   summary:     add a
```

Ahh, we changed our mind. We are missing one file. Let's add it (and so
add something to the hg history):

```
$ touch b
$ hg add b
$ hg commit -m 'add b'
```

We would like to move the `0.1.0` tag to the tip. Let's try:

```
$ hg tag 0.1.0
abort: tag '0.1.0' already exists (use -f to force)
```

Quite clear. Let's try again:

```
hg tag --force 0.1.0
```

What is the history ?

```
hg log -G
@  changeset:   3:04b62f2a9b16
|  tag:         tip
|  summary:     Added tag 0.1.0 for changeset 3d8bb8a977e6
|
o  changeset:   2:3d8bb8a977e6
|  tag:         0.1.0
|  summary:     add b
|
o  changeset:   1:9352d8865ee5
|  summary:     Added tag 0.1.0 for changeset a4cab63b7c86
|
o  changeset:   0:a4cab63b7c86
   summary:     add a
```

As we can see, the tag has moved to the new location.

For curiosity, how are tags stored? In a simple text file:

```
$ cat .hgtags
a4cab63b7c868638e51a45d93443b1a0eb56e1e4 0.1.0
a4cab63b7c868638e51a45d93443b1a0eb56e1e4 0.1.0
3d8bb8a977e6be693a30c30d7d7675d04623690f 0.1.0
```

If the `.hgtags` file has multiple entries with the same tag, the last one
wins. This is seen often when merging branches.

Left to the reader: clearly these changes are local. You have to push to
bitbucket to make them public.

**EDIT**

To answer the additional question: is there a way to remove a tag, or to rename a tag for the same commit ?

The safest way is not to rename the tag, it is to add the new tag name for the same commit (with `hg tag -r REV`). Said in another way: a single commit can have associated as many tags as you want.

It is also possible to remove the tag, simply by removing the corresponding line from `.hgtags`. This is delicate to get right, because there is one copy of that file per branch, and it could come back as the result of a merge.

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there any way to remove a tag? Or, assume that you've typed it in a wrong way (e.g. 0.1.=), and want to change the tag, for the same commit. How do you do that?

Comment: @nightcod3r I updated the answer to reflect this new question.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is possible to delete a tag. This can be done from the commit's view: the tag has a gray `X` next to it.

The tagged commit can be found on the commits' page. It is the top-most one for the tag.

Notes:

- This answers the question "How to untag in Bitbucket" - I am using git, not mercurial.
- I have still added the answer, because this page ranks high in search engine results.